# Xcode Preprocessor comparison

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have an application which I would like to use preprocessors with. I use "xcodebuild" and pass through a parameter `APPLICATION_TYPE=` which can either be `DEV` or `PROD`.

I then want to define a flag to then use in my code based on which of `dev` or prod has been used.

Code:

```
#if APPLICATION_TYPE == DEV
    #define DEVELOPMENT
#elif APPLICATION_TYPE == PROD
#define PRODUCTION
#endif
```

The problem I seem to have is no matter what I pass into the "xcodebuild" it will always define DEVELOPMENT.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use numeric values if you want comparisons.

Instead of defining things like `APPLICATION_TYPE`, it's easier to define a macro for every application type, e.g. `APLICATION_IS_DEV=1` and `APLICATION_IS_PROD=1` and add a preprocessor asserting that at least one of them is defined and they are not both defined simultaneously.

However, with Xcode there is a much better way to specify preprocessing macros - just create a special scheme or target and don't switch between macros. Switch between schemes or targets.